# mongoose has many relationship with parent id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Region model and an Activity model. The Activity model has `region_id` key that references the Region.

In my definition of my Region model, I'd like to have it reference all it's activities but have been unsuccessful. Any ideas?

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import Tag from './Tag';
const schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  url: String,
  state: {type: String, default: 'California'},
  stateRrl: {type: String, default: null},
  longitude: String,
  latitude: String,
  country: {type: String, default: 'United States'},
  description: {type: String, default: ''},
  factsTitle: {type: String, default: ''},
  infoTitle: {String, default: ''},

  // Assocations
  activities: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Activity'}],
  tags: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag'}]
});
```

Comment: I  don't see `Region` model in your code.

Comment: that is the region model